# Remove values / nan / empty string("") from list of lists in python

Tags: python

Given:

```
a = [["a","",""],
 ["b","",""],
 ["c","d",""]]

b = [["a", nan, nan],
["b", nan, nan],
["c","d", nan]]
```

I would like to remove the value which is nan or empty string.

This is my current code:

```
while("" in a):
    a.remove("")
```

and

```
b = [x for x in b if str(x) != nan]
```

but both don't work, what should I do?

Comment: `nan` as in `numpy.nan` or `str` (`"nan"`)?

Comment: `a` is a list-of-lists.  `""` is not a _direct_ member of `a`.

Comment: @Chris is NaN in the excel before i change it to list ,so I guess is numpy.nan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the corrected version.

```
from math import isnan  # numpy.isnan can also be used instead

# If the list contains only strings, `if e != ""` can be simplied to `if e`
a = [[e for e in l if e != ""] for l in a]

# Use isnan function to check for nan values
b = [[e for e in l if not isnan(e)] for l in b]
```

Answer (score 0):

`x for x in b` only looks at list level 1.

Try this:

```
b = [[n for n in b] for x in b if n not in ('nan', "")]
```

Answer (score 0):

list.remove("")  removes the first "" element in list. a doesn't contain "". You should do it for every sublist in a or b.

```
for l in a:
    while "" in l:
        l.remove("")
```